# Blank select tag form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, html-select

I'm trying to add selectable options to a select tag by being able to select one of the user's lists (a user has_many lists and a list belongs to a user). 
Here is my controller code (assume I have @user defined already):

```
@options_for_select = []
@user.lists.each do |list|
    @options_for_select.push([list.title, list.id])
end
```

And then, in my view, I have this:

```
<%= select_tag(:option, @options_for_select, selected: :option, class: "form-control" ) %>
```

But this renders a blank select tag with no select options.
[image]

The thing is, when I do `puts "options for select are " + @options_for_select.inspect`, I get this:

```
options for select are [["List 1", 1], ["List 2", 2], ["List 3", 3]
```

So why isn't it working?

Comment: Shouldn't you make use of the `options_for_select` and pass your @options_for_select? http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was include options_for_select(@options_for_select) in my code. Instead of

```
<%= select_tag(:option, @options_for_select, selected: :option, class: "form-control" ) %>
```

I did

```
<%= select_tag(:option, options_for_select(@options_for_select), selected: :option, class: "form-control" ) %>
```

Agh.

Comment: As I said in the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `:include_blank => false` option:

```
= f.input :option, :as => :select,  :collection => options_for_select(@options_for_select), :include_blank => false
```